# Own jQuery plugin only working on first selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've had a go at writing my first plugin. It is a simple jQuery plugin that reorders the DOM based on screen width. If the plugin is used on a single selector, like `$("#box3").domorder();` it works as expected.

However, if multiple selectors are used to call the function, or the function is called multiple times, the function only works once, on the first selector it comes to.

I have the `each(function(){})` iterating over each selector, but I'm obviously missing something.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L385U/)

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    $.fn.domorder = function(options) {

        var settings = {
            breakpoint : 960,
            targetContainer : $(this).parent(),
            targetPosition : "start"
        };

        if (options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        return this.each(function(i, el) {
            /* remember selector's original order position */
            var originalLocation = {};
            if ($(el).prev().length) {
                /* not originally first child */
                originalLocation.prev = $(el).prev()[0];
            } else {
                /* originally a first child */
                originalLocation.parent = $(el).parent()[0];
            }

            var initiatedomorder = function() {
                var winW = $(window).width();

                if (winW < settings.breakpoint && !$("body").hasClass("domorder-reordered")) {
                    /* dom the order of the item */

                    if (settings.targetPosition === "start") {
                        $(el).prependTo(settings.targetContainer[0]);
                    } else {
                        $(el).appendTo(settings.targetContainer[0]);
                    }
                    $("body").addClass("domorder-reordered");
                } else if (winW >= settings.breakpoint && $("body").hasClass("domorder-reordered")) {
                    /* return the reordered item back into the orignal flow */
                    if (originalLocation.parent) {
                        /* element was a first child */
                        $(originalLocation.parent).prepend(el);
                    } else {
                        /* element was not a first child */
                        /* add a line break to preserve inline-block spacing */
                        $(originalLocation.prev).after(el).after("\n");
                    }
                    $("body").removeClass("domorder-reordered");
                }
            };

            initiatedomorder();

            $(window).resize(function() {
                initiatedomorder();
            });
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("body").addClass("domorder-reordered");` cause the problem since only the first iteration will do the ordering.

maybe you should change the `$("body")` to something like `$(el.parentNode)`.

[check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/terryleonhart/fJnNu/)

Comment: Thanks, seems so obvious now

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the class to the body on the first iteration of the loop. so in the second iteration body has the class and wot go inside the ordering code. you have to rethink about the location of addClass and removeClass

and put the following code outside the each

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    initiatedomorder();
});
```

Comment: Can't move the resize handler outside the each since initiatedomorder is defined within the each.